# Access only to home page for no authorized users

Tags: redirection

Anonymus should only have access to home page and see all content there. 
When anonymus click any link, he should be redirected to login page.

```
function template_preprocess(&$variables, $hook) {
  $access_pages = array('dp/admin', 'user/login', 'user/password');
  if (!$variables['is_front'] && !$variables['logged_in'] && !in_array($_GET['q'], $access_pages)) {
    drupal_goto('dp/admin');
  }
}
```

Is this right? Is there better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your permissions are set perfectly, then installing this module may prove helpful in this case

[Redirect 403 to User Login (r4032login)](https://www.drupal.org/project/r4032login)

Comment: thanks. i also use https://www.drupal.org/project/path_access